# Matlab 2016b: Determine unassigned symbolic functions of an expression

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

how can I determine *unassigned symbolic functions* (`syms f(t)`) of an expression. Excluding *symbolic math functions* (`sin`,...) and *symbolic variables* (`syms a`).

For example:

```
syms a(t) b(t) c
expr = a(t)*diff(b, t) + c*diff(a,t)^2 + sin(c*pi)*cos(b);
```

examining *symbolic variables*

```
>> symvar(expr)
[ c, t]
```

and how to do it for *unassigned symbolic functions*

```
>> XXXXX(expr)
[ a(t), b(t), diff(a, t), diff(b, t)]
% or
[ a(t), b(t)]
% or
[ a, b]
```

Comment: `isSymType(b(t),'symfun')` would allow you to check, if you got such a type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MATLAB 2019a and newer

```
>> X = findSymType(expr,'symfun')

X =

[ a(t), b(t)]
```

From the documentation:

> Find an unassigned symbolic function of type 'symfun' in the equation.

For previous MATLAB versions, I don't see such a function. Only option I see is to write a function yourself.

```
>> feval(symengine,'type',expr)

ans =

_plus

>> feval(symengine,'type',b(t))

ans =

function

>> feval(symengine,'type',sin(t))

ans =

sin
```

The mupad type function allows you to identify the type of an expression, you are looking for "function". Here is some code, which looks for all terms of a certain type:

```
function z=mst(x,symtype)
y=children(x);
if strcmpi(char(feval(symengine,'type',x)),symtype)
    z=x;
else
    z=[];
end
if ~isequal(x,y)
for ix=1:numel(y)
   z=[z;mst(y(ix),symtype)];
end
end
end
```

an example call:

```
>> mst(expr,'function')

ans =

 b(t)
 a(t)
 a(t)
 b(t)
```

Comment: I really like this way, but this function was introduced in R2019a :(

Comment: I added some alternative, which hopefully works in your MATLAB version.